# ¿Problemas con hashing de encriptación python flask?

Tags: python, flask

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow tengo la siguiente pregunta:

Yo intento hacer un registro de usuario con la contraseña encriptada y guardarla en la base de datos una vez hecho el registro y haber validado el correo al loguearme me dice que la contraseña es incorrecta siendo esta la misma que ingrese en el registro luego noto que los valores de encriptado son diferentes con el mismo valor de la contraseña aquí esta el codigo:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt as crypt


from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
import smtplib
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql://root:root@localhost/login_flask"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Bootstrap(app)


configure = app.config.update(
DEBUG=True,
MAIL_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com",
MAIL_PORT=465,
MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
MAIL_USERNAME="<correo>",
MAIL_PASSWORD="<password>"
)
mail=Mail(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'


# ======================= #
#       Here is The
#           Model
# ======================= #
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ ="user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    token = db.Column(db.String(1))
    # def __init__(self, id, username, password, email, token):
    #   self.id = id
    #   self.username = username
    #   self.password = password
    #   self.email = email
    #   self.token = token

    # def is_active(self):
    #   return True
    # def get_id(self):
    #   return (self.id)
    # def is_anonymous(self):
    #   return False
    # def is_authenticated(self):
    #   return True


###########################
#   python
#   from __init__ import db
#   db.create_all()
#   exit()
###########################

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
# ======================= #
#       Here is The
#           Form
# ======================= #

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Usuario', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('Contraseña', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    remember = BooleanField('Recordar')


class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message="Invalid Email"), Length(max=50) ])
    username = StringField('Usuario', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('Contraseña', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    password_replicate = PasswordField('Repite Contraseña', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])

# ======================= #
#       Here is The
#           Code
# ======================= #


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/login/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        passw = form.password.data
        passw = crypt.encrypt((form.password.data))
        print("pass1: "+passw)
        print("pass2: "+user.password)
        if user:
            if passw == user.password:
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                session["logged_in"] = True
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    #   if user and user.token==1:
    #       if check_password_hash(user.password, passw):
    #       login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
    #       return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        return ("<h1>Invalida Username or Password!</h1>")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)

@app.route("/dashboard/")
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")

@app.route("/logout/")
def logout():
    return render_template("logout.html")

@app.route("/register/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    try:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            username = form.username.data
            email = form.email.data
            if form.password.data == form.password_replicate.data:
                hashed_password=crypt.encrypt((form.password.data))
                verification_email = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
                username_verification = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
                print("hash: " + hashed_password)
                try:
                    new_user = User(username=username, email=email, password=hashed_password, token=0)
                    db.session.add(new_user)
                    db.session.commit()
                    activation_email(email, username, hashed_password)
                    return render_template("email_sender.html")
                except Exception as e:
                    return("Email or Username is used")
        return render_template("register.html", form=form)
    except Exception as e:
        return (str(e))


def activation_email(email, username, hashed_password):
    session['logged_in'] = True
    session['username'] = username
    msg=Message("Send Email for example %s" %username, sender="mendezlinaresi@gmail.com", recipients=[email])
    msg.body=str("Active your account\t http://localhost:5000/activate_email/%s/%s/%s" %(email, username, hashed_password))
    return mail.send(msg)


@app.route("/activate_email/<string:email>/<string:username>/<string:hashed_password>")
def activate_email(email, username, hashed_password):
    token=User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    token.token=1
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("activate_email.html", name = username, email=email)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.secret_key = "aa42724c5b253a8775a7fcf187a88d82af259c3f88867b3640187783"
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = "filesystem"
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Tysaic, acabo de editar tu pregunta para borrar los datos del correo que habías puesto, te sugiero que modifiques lo antes posible la contraseña de gmail. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias hermano de verdad hare eso.

Comment: @Tysaic Al hashear la contraseña es probable que esta esté aumentado de tamaño. Si el campo "password" en tu base de datos es más pequeño que la contraseña hasheada,solo se estará guardando una parte del hash y por eso al hacer la comparación te falla. Prueba a aumentar el tamaño del campo password en la base de datos( y también en la clase User) a 150-170 caracteres.

Comment: @KuroshD. Oye muchas gracias de verdad me funciono pulgar arriba!

Comment: @Tysaic no hay de qué!

Answer (score 0):

@Tysaic, posiblemente tienes este problema dado que tu string solo acepta 80 caracteres debes ampliarlo como minimo a 94 caracteres esta asi: `password = db.Column(db.String(80))` y debe quedar asi `password = db.Column(db.String(94))` este mismo problema me sucedio a mi con python 3.6. agradecimiento a @cote en el foro de codigofacilito.